# maven 3 interproject depedency with war packaging

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, dependencies

I have Eclipse Indigo and M2E plugin installed.

So essentially I have a standard maven web project (let's call it proj-service) that is built into a war file in the package phase. This all works fine. My issue comes in when I have my other project (lets call it proj1) that needs to use classes from proj-service. I know that this is possible in maven+eclipse but it does not seem to be working at the moment. I have the following in proj1's pom right now:

```
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>proj1</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>proj1</name>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Maven Repo Libraries -->
        .........
        <!-- Interproject dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.foo</groupId>
            <artifactId>proj-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>lsoap</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>          
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately with Maven's war packaging you can't reuse classes from war project, because there is no direct build artifact you can use for the class path.

So, in order to do share classes properly you need to extract those common classes into a 3rd common project (jar packaging) and make it as dependency in both of your other projects.

Comment: And I would built it as a jar? And if so why does it even give an option for packaging?

Comment: Also, the issue here is that proj-service is a web service. proj1 is a project that depends on that webservice. Are there no options?

Comment: Yes, common project will have to have jar packaging. You have war and jar packaging. War packaged build artifact can't be used as dependency contributing to classpath.

Comment: Ugh, that sucks. Let me figure out how I am going to do this. Would this be done usually by separating out interfaces from implementation?

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing your code. But you should know what classes your projects need to share. For web services it could be the code you generate from wsdl or similar metadata.

Comment: I'll figure it out. It is my code after all. Thanks for the answer, was really frustrating me.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to change the configuration of your proj-service project in the way to change the configuration of the maven-war-plugin:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
      <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
       ...
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

This will it make possible to use the classes from the proj-service project in other projects via the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
  <version>myVersion</myVersion>
  <classifier>classes</classifier>
</dependency>
```

This will result in changing your dependency from:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>proj-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

into:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>proj-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <classifier>classes</classifier/>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Ah, this is interesting. This probably would have been the more "correct" solution since me taking out interface and utility classes from the web service was largely unnecessary due to the fact that nobody except the web service uses them. Thank you for the answer. Upvoted!